# unable to access R packages under user account in opencpu

Tags: r, opencpu

I am trying to access R packages which were installed under a user's account from opencpu. I can see that the package is installed when I start R as that user:

```
> installed.packages() 
           Package      LibPath                                         
RLIM       "RLIM"       "/limdata/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0"
...
> system('whoami');
ali
```

However, when I try to access the library from opencpu, I get errors indicating the package was not found:

```
$ curl -L http://<my.server>/ocpu/user/ali/library/RLIM
there is no package called 'RLIM'

In call:
find.package(pkgname, lib.loc = lib.loc)
# from same server, to confirm opencpu is running... 
$ curl -L http://<my.server>/ocpu/library 
base
bitops
boot
brew
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Platform info:

- Host: Ubuntu 12.04
- opencpu-server 1.0.4-precise0
- opencpu-lib: 1.0.4-precise0
- R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your home library is not in the default location of `/home/ali/`. Therefore some additional steps are needed to access your packages.

First of all, the default security profile won't allow OpenCPU to access `/limdata/`. To verify that this is indeed the problem, have a look at `/var/log/kern.log` and search for lines containing `APPARMOR` and `DENIED`. Please read the section titled *Customizing the security profile* in the [PDF server manual](http://jeroenooms.github.com/opencpu-manual/opencpu-manual.pdf).

To add your home library to the security profile, edit `/etc/apparmor.d/opencpu.d/custom` and add these lines:

```
/limdata/ r,
/limdata/** mrix,
```

Afterwards, restart apparmor and opencpu:

```
 sudo service apparmor restart
 sudo service opencpu restart
```

That should take care of the security restrictions. I hope that will do it; honestly I haven't tested a scenario where the home directory is outside of `/home` but I think if your `R_LIBS_USER` environment variable is properly configured, it should work. If not let me know :-)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I did not see any DENIED entries in kern.log. Editing /etc/apparmor.d/opencpu.d/custom and restarting apparmor and opencpu did not resolve the issue. However, it was peculiar that when I issued GET on /ocpu/user resource, the only user listed was the one whose home was under /home. I added a new user under /home and I can see the users home library. I will try to dig further into R_LIBS_USER and post my findings. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I think I know whats causing the issue. The userhome() function in userlibpath.R returns '/home' if the effective user is root or www-data which is what the apache process is running as. So the function userlibpath executed as either user root or www-data returns "/home/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0" which is incorrect while running the same function as user 'ali' returns the correct path: "/limdata/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0"

Comment: Yes you are right. If you would like to suggest a more robust way of detecting user home dir, send a pull request :-) Perhaps a temporary workaround would be to make a symlink from `/home/ali` to `/limdata/ali` ?

Comment: Send me a email if you'd like to help get this fixed in the next version.

Comment: @AliGuler @Jeroen How did you solve this problem? My home directory is `/home/deploy` where `~/R/library` is located. From `~/.Renviron` I point to `R_LIBS_USER=~/R/library`. Also tried `R_LIBS`. No Luck.